# Why is there a comma in "Man discusses his, wife's experience"

Tags: grammar, commas

Why is there a comma after "his" in the headline? Does this mean his AND his wife's experience? Is it correct english, or slang?

"Man discusses his, wife's experience being injured during the Boston marathon bombings."

Source: http://abcnews.go.com/US/video/boston-marathon-explosion-video-attack-victim-hard-mad-18969745

Comment: Headlines have very relaxed "rules" of grammar; see also: http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/02/18/the-grammar-of-newspaper-headlines/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's short for "Man discusses his *and his wife's* experience...."  It does not mean "Man discusses *his wife*'s experience."

News headlines are trying to achieve maximum impact with as few words as possible, so they often take liberties with omitting unnecessary words, while preserving the message of the story.

This particular headline might be somewhat *awkward* English, but there's nothing technically incorrect about it.

Comment: I see this as a uniquely American style. It's frequently used in headlines there, but I don't recall ever seeing it in any UK newspapers/websites.

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice in the US to use a comma in place of "and" in headlines.

Answer (score 2):

This is an offshoot of the usage of the serial comma, but without the conjunction.

"Man discusses his, wife's, son's, and daughter's experience." is typical and grammatically correct. It is expected that the "and" is implicit in the comma, and the list can be shortened to as few as two items.

Comment: *And* is often omitted before *wife*; *his* can only be omitted in headlines (and looks strange to me even then).

Comment: his can't ever be omitted without losing information, in this type of sentence (fragment)

Comment: ?? *His* **has** been omitted before *wife's*. This is peculiar, but does not reduce information.

Comment: @TimLymington ahh, you mean the difference in "his, his wife's" and "his, wife's". I thought you meant the still-there "his" could also be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Other answers explain why this happens. I will add that this is standard practice in the U.S., where a comma in a headline almost always means "and."